# Selecionar dois atributos de duas tabelas diferentes numa view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, query, linq

Tenho o modelo (superclasse) `Pessoa` e o modelo `Aluno`

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
        this.Escola = new HashSet<Escola>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }           
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Morada { get; set; }          
    public virtual ICollection<Escola> Escola { get; set; }
}

public partial class Aluno
{
    public Aluno()

    [Key, ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }    
    public String NomeEscola { get; set; }
    public String AnoEscolar { get; set; }
    public String TurmaEscolar { get; set; }    
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Pretendo fazer um selectlist do atributo Nome numa view em que o AlunoID seja igual à PessoaID
Tentei com o seguinte código no controlador do Aluno mas sem sucesso

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Aluno aluno = db.aluno.Find(id);
    if (aluno == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.AlunoID = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaID", "Nome", aluno.AlunoID);
    return View(aluno);
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Tu queres pegar no teu `contexto`, todos os objetos que tenham a propriedade `PessoaID` igual à `aluno.AlunoID`?

Comment: Sim , pretendia obter os nomes da tabela Pessoa que correspondesse ao ID da tabela Aluno, em que esses nomes seriam enviados para uma Listbox. Ja criei uma ViewModel que penso ser necessário...

Answer (score 1):

Sua modelagem está incorreta. Um `Aluno` é uma `Pessoa`, portanto `Aluno` precisa ser uma derivação de `Pessoa`:

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
    // Isto está incorreto, então comentei. 
    // Quem inicializa propriedades de navegação é o Entity Framework.
    /* public Pessoa()
    {
        this.Escola = new HashSet<Escola>();
    } */

    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }           
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Morada { get; set; }          
    public virtual ICollection<Escola> Escola { get; set; }
}

public partial class Aluno : Pessoa
{
    // Este construtor está sem utilidade, então também retirei.
    // public Aluno()
    public String NomeEscola { get; set; }
    public String AnoEscolar { get; set; }
    public String TurmaEscolar { get; set; }    

    // Esta propriedade de navegação não é necessária.
    // public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

No contexto, é interessante ter os dois `DbSet`, tanto de `Pessoa` quanto de `Aluno`, mapeados:

```
    public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
```

Se você quiser selecionar qualquer tipo de pessoa, use `contexto.Pessoas`. Se quiser selecionar especificamente alunos, use `contexto.Alunos`.

Seu *Controller* ficará assim:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Aluno aluno = db.aluno.Find(id);
    if (aluno == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.AlunoID = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "PessoaID", "Nome", aluno.AlunoID);
    return View(aluno);
}
```

Comment: Não consigo fazer o update database derivado á herança Pessoa Aluno

Comment: Então, possivelmente você vai ter que gerar suas *Migrations* novamente. Esta resposta muda radicalmente sua modelagem.